# Sort questions by votes ASCENDING

Tags: support, sorting

Is it possible to see the list of questions sorted by votes in *ascending* order - ie see the worst questions first?

I would have thought that clicking twice on the heading would reverse the sort...

Comment: Alternate proposal: Trainwrecks tab. "Come and laugh at the riff-raff."

Comment: Worst questions first... wouldn't that be `votes ASCENDING`?

Comment: oops yes - fixed. :)

Comment: @Anthony - yes.. though actually I was thinking of a way of finding questions to close, review or edit into shape... :)

Comment: You missed the body in italics.

Comment: Yup I sure did ;)

Comment: @Taryn, if you're trying to find "questions to close, review or edit into shape," why not just use the `/review` page?

Comment: Been there, done that ;) The review page mainly has contributions from new users. Not the old cruft. Though I am also motivated by the "trainwreck" curiosity on this one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is currently no way to sort questions by "lowest score first". None of the sort options are reversible.

You can generally get the same effect of reversing a sort by just starting from the last page and moving upwards. So, on `votes` you can start at the last page to go from worst to best, on `newest` you can start at the last page to go from eldest first, and so on and so forth. This kind of option is somewhat redundant with adding a new sort order - it's part why we got rid of the "newest" sort option on answers within a question.

The only time this particularly fails is if you're on a search criteria that provides more than 5000 results. In which case, I might suggest giving [Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/) a try. It won't be necessarily up-to-date, but when it comes to the lowest of the low, it'll probably be pretty accurate.

Comment: In particular, this Data Explorer query does roughly what you have in mind: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/33037/most-popular-bad-questions