# In Stack Overflow, is there any way to find the questions with maximum downvotes?

Tags: feature-request, search, down-votes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the most upvoted/downvoted questions and answers on the sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11017/what-are-the-most-upvoted-downvoted-questions-and-answers-on-the-sites)

In Stack Overflow, we can find highest voted questions.

If there is a way to find the questions with more down votes, it will be fun.

I am just curious to know that, am I the maximum negative-voted questioner in Meta?

I am talking about this :-)

https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93555/what-moderators-do-in-stack-overflow

It's a way to find the worst questioners. If I am able to see others questions with greater downvote counts, it will increase my confidence.

Comment: lol Losers start downvoting again without telling anything

Comment: You're far from the most downvoted questioner ♪ Also, see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93420/sort-questions-by-votes-ascending/93425#93425).

Comment: FYI, [downvoting on Meta is different](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47634/how-does-meta-stack-overflow-work/47635#47635) than it is on "normal" sites. I didn't downvote you, but I'm guessing that the people who did were thinking that there's no good use case for the feature you're requesting.

Comment: downvoters buddies can look into the answers

Comment: @popular thanks for the info. if any one ask anything provocative it will be suppressed. Its good in some cases anyway.

Comment: @zod - you're not being suppressed, notice that your really terrible ideas have not been deleted.  You are being overruled by the community, which is how it should work.

Comment: @jnk Did you ever think this, why an already downvoted question is not getting upvoted by anyone. Community have different people with different views . Atleast someone  will think i am right. But this downvoting give a feel that this question is useless.

Comment: @Zod - Downvoted questions DO get upvotes all the time.  They just aren't yours, apparently.  It could also be the people that might agree with you aren't active on meta.

Comment: @jnk "DO get upvotes all the time " is wrong. and you not at all active compared to me.

Comment: @Zod - If by "Not at all active" you mean "Don't ask a lot of terrible questions" then you are correct.  Somehow I have been around 1 month longer than you and have over 3x your rep, though.  Must be through my idleness!

Comment: @JNK also thanks for the mysterious downvote on my old question from months ago!

Comment: @JNK you are not the only jackal here :-)

Comment: @Zod - you are welcome.  Your comments about how "active" you are made me read some of your questions, and I did indeed DV one because you were insulting a commenter for no reason (kind of like here).

Comment: was that about gordon !! i made a mistake ..actually i upvote you for one answer :-) leave it man. carryon with your work. am bored

Comment: See the dup-link for the queries; FWIW, you're not even *close* - [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42601/should-we-have-a-policy-about-too-much-downvoting) is the most down-voted question on MSO, with currently **65 down-votes** and 37 up-votes.

Comment: LOL the first question got +7 and duplicate got  -6 WTF

Answer (score 1):

http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/questions?order=asc&sort=votes

http://api.meta.stackoverflow.com/1.1/questions?order=asc&sort=votes

Note: This is sorted by post score, not by only downvotes.

Answer (score 1):

Yes questions can be sorted by votes.  You can sort first by votes and jump to the last page to see the questions with the most down votes.

Like so:
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=votes

The lowest voted question on Meta at the moment is:
[Moderators should not close crap, flamebait questions, let the community](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92508/moderators-should-not-close-crap-flamebait-questions-let-the-community)